# Generic method that accepts generic list of Expression<Func>

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming, generic-list

I have declared multiple of these variables, but how can I then put them into a generic list?

```
Expression<Func<poco, string>> fieldToUpdate1 = x => x.Name;
Expression<Func<poco, bool>> fieldToUpdate2 = x => x.Id;
```

Currently I can only specify one type for the generic list.

So I can either get a  `List<string>` or `List<bool>`. But not both. I want to be able to have a generic list that accepts both so I can pass that list as a parameter.

Use case:
The use case I am trying to do is create a generic wrapper for the Mongo method updateOne. With the below signature. I want to create a generic wrapper that will accept two parameters. I can use these parameters to call the actual mongo implementation. Something like this:

```
GenericWrapper(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter, List<(Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> expression, TField actual value)>)
```

The problem is that TField can only be one type. So I can only do this:

```
Expression<Func<Student, string>> fieldToUpdate1 = x => x.name;
Expression<Func<Student, int>> fieldToUpdate2 = x => x.testScore;
var expressions = new List<(Expression<Func<Student, int>>    expression, int value)>();
var item1 = (expression: fieldToUpdate2, value: 4);
var item2 = (expression: fieldToUpdate1, value: "test");
expressions.Add(item1);
//I can't add item2 since its of a different type. I can only  pass a list of the same type. And my generic wrapper function will only accept a list of one type
```

http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_UpdateOne__1.htm

```
public static UpdateResult UpdateOne<TDocument>(
this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection,
Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter,
UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update,
UpdateOptions options = null,
CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
```

)

Any ideas on how to make this generic wrapper?

Comment: You could specify `object` as the list type and cast later on when reading from the list.

Comment: Also it can be useful to make one step back and ask youself: "why i need such a wierd thing?". Maybe you will get to a more reasonable desing.

Comment: you will have to target the keys. `Key1` and `Key2` when you want to pass along a specific parameter. You could loop through w/e you want to pass in, and then check the type before you add it to the key.

Comment: "but how can I then put them into a generic list?" what exactly do you want to put in a list? `fieldToUpdate1` and `fieldToUpdate2` ? or do you want to put the return values of the `Func` into lists ? sorry (it might be too early for my brain) but I am confused and the question is not clear to me

Comment: it also sounds a little bit like an XY problem. Can you may be post a use case where you use `fieldToUpdate1` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Expression<T>` inherits from `Expression` you can put it into a `List<Expression>`.

```
List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();
expressions.Add(fieldToUpdate1);
expressions.Add(fieldToUpdate2);
```

Comment: As his expressions are of type Expression<Func<…>> he can use `LambdaExpression` instead of `Expression` to ensure that at least only lambda expressions are provided as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object as the return value:

```
Expression<Func<poco, object>> fieldToUpdate1 = x => x.Name;
Expression<Func<poco, object>> fieldToUpdate2 = x => x.Id;
List<Expression<Func<poco, object>>> testList = new List<Expression<Func<poco, object>>>();
testList.Add(fieldToUpdate1);
testList.Add(fieldToUpdate2);
```

Anyway, the general design seems a bit strange, since at the end, you have to cast at least the results.

Comment: The answer of Matthias works as well and does not even require your poco object.